# Measuring time taken by a function to execute for runtime analysis

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, sorting, time

so I'm trying to measure the time for a computational complexity analysis (so calculating the run time) but my code won't run, it keeps displaying an error. If any of you guys can help me solve this error I'd appreciate it a lot thank you! Here's my code:

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

// to generate random LARGE list
function randomName(n) {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  let name = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    name += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  return name;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var shoes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  shoes.push(new Shoe(randomName(20), randomNumber(50, 5000), randomName(7)));
}

//bubblesort
function bubbleSort(shoes) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length - 1; i++) {
    
      // converting prices to numbers
      if (+shoes[i].price > +shoes[i + 1].price) {
        var temp = shoes[i];
        shoes[i] = shoes[i + 1];
        shoes[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  return shoes;
}

bubbleSort(shoes);
console.log('Bubble Sort:\n', shoes);

const {performance} = require('perfHooks');
start = performance.now();
bubbleSort();
 end = performance.now();
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Be more specific please.

Comment: so first it was performance is not defined this was my performance code before:

Comment: ` var t0 = performance.now()

bubbleSort()   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 

var t1 = performance.now()
console.log("Call to bubbleSort " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")`

Comment: What is `t1` and `t0`? Neither variable appear in your code. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem code.

Comment: it was my code before but I adjusted it to the current one in my post @Dshiz

Comment: @Dshiz thanks for your edit suggestion I approved it would you be able to help me implement a function I can measure the time required to execute another function?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the **exact** error message

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to require `perfHooks`, because `performance.now()` is a [built in Web API method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

I have adjusted your code based on the example provided at the MDN link above.

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

// to generate random LARGE list
function randomName(n) {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  let name = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    name += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  return name;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var shoes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  shoes.push(new Shoe(randomName(20), randomNumber(50, 5000), randomName(7)));
}

//bubblesort
function bubbleSort(shoes) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length - 1; i++) {
    
      // converting prices to numbers
      if (+shoes[i].price > +shoes[i + 1].price) {
        var temp = shoes[i];
        shoes[i] = shoes[i + 1];
        shoes[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  return shoes;
}

const t0 = performance.now();

bubbleSort(shoes);

console.log('Bubble Sort:\n', shoes);

const t1 = performance.now();

console.log(`Call to bubbleSort took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`)
```

Comment: when I run the code snipped on stack overflow it works but it doesn't work on my IDE it just keeps saying "performance is not defined"

Comment: Are you trying to run this on a node server? If so, it won't work. It is a browser Web API method.

Comment: yeah I'm running it on a node server on repl.it. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You will need to update your question or create a new one because that is a different question.

Comment: oh I'll have to wait 90 minutes for that and I really needed help on short notice but thank you i guess

Comment: ok thank you I appreciate it but is there no way you can tell me how to do the same thing but with a Node Server?

Comment: Try `const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')` -- [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_measurement_apis). In the future, please specify the platform you are using and having trouble on.